# Find $AB : EB$ in the given $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

**Question:**

> In $\triangle ABC$, $D$ is a point on $AC$ and divides $AC$ in the ratio $1 : 2$. $E$ is a point on $AB$ such that $CE$ divides $BD$ in the ratio $2 : 1$. Find $AB : EB$.

I tried to solve it by connecting $E$ and $D$ which didn't work. So then I tried connecting $A$ and $G$ (where $G$ is the point of intersection of $CE$ and $BD$) but that didn't work too. Then I didn't know what else to do.

Please help.

Comment: The point $D$ defines $BD$ which is cut into the ratio $2:1$ by $CE$. That makes it relevant, right? To define the line segment $BD$?

Comment: No no, I wasn't asking. Just clarifying the question being asked by the other user.

Comment: I misread the problem, sorry.

Comment: @ajotatxe happens with me too, no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a cute little trick by using the uniqueness of center of mass.

Since we know that $AD:DC=1:2$, place a mass of $2$ units at $A$ and a mass of $1$ units at $C$. Then note that $D$ is exactly at the center of mass (com) of this configuration, with mass $3$ units. Now let $BD$ intersect $CE$ at $F$. Since $BF:FD=2:1$, place a mass of $\frac32$ units at $B$ and note that $F$ is again exactly the com of the masses at $B$ and $D$, with a mass of $\frac92$ units.

Here's the fun part. The mass at the com of the whole triangular configuration should be exactly $2+\frac32+1=\frac92$ units, and since $D$ is the com of $A$ and $C$, $F$ *has* to be the com of the whole triangle (why?). But then $E$ is the com of $A$ and $B$ and thus $AE:AB=\frac37:1=3:7$ and thus $AB:EB=7:(7-3)=7:4$ and we are done!

Comment: This is very interesting though how can we be sure that E is com of AB and likewise F is com of whole triangle? I thought com of any triangle would lie at it's centroid but that's not the case here. Also for the rod AC, it is fine to consider D as com since we're afterwards giving weights to A and C but in case of AB how we can definitively say E is com?

Comment: the com of the triangle is at the centroid when the weights are all 1. $E$ is the com of $AB$ precisely because the line segment $CE$ passes through the com of the whole triangle, that is $F$.  Now, to show that $F$ is the com of the whole triangle, note that the com must lie on the line segment $BD$ (since $D$ is the com of the $A$ and $C$). Since you know the mass at the com of the triangle, and it agrees with the com of $B$ and $D$, the com has to be at $F$. It's just a bunch of arguments using the uniqueness of com (contd...)

Comment: (contd...)  I will leave it to you show that any line through a vertex and the com of the triangle passes through the com of the opposite edge.

Comment: Alright, got it. Wow!

Answer (score 2):

You may find [Menelaus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) useful, as well as the proof.
According to your description, the line $EC$ cut through three edges of the triangle $ABD$ at point $E$ on edge $AB$, point $G$ on BD, and point $C$ on $AD$.
Then we have
$$
\frac{|AE|}{|EB|}\cdot\frac{|BG|}{|GD|}\cdot\frac{|DC|}{|CA|} = 1
$$
It should be easy enough to see what is next.
If I get your question in the right way, the answer should be $7/4$.

Comment: This, looks correct to me, you should update your answer to make it a complete solution, otherwise this looks more like a hint. For example, add that the theorem applied to $\triangle ABD$

Comment: Woah, nice. This ended before it even started.

Comment: Hey, your answer is great too and thought a lot which one to mark accepted. Ultimately went with one which I found highly innovative. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Using analytic geometry, we can put WLOG $A=(-1,0)$, $C=(2,0)$, $B=(3t,3s)$ (where $s\neq 0$), $D=(0,0)$. Let $F$ be the intersection of $CE$ and $BD$. Since $\overrightarrow{BD}=(-3t,-3s)$, $\overrightarrow{BF}=(-2t,-2s)$, so $F=(t,s)$ and $\overrightarrow{CF}=(t-2,s)$. The equation of the line $CE=CF$ is $sx-(t-2)y=2s$, and the equation of $AB$ is $3sx-(3t+1)y=-3s$. The point $E$ is the solution of the system
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3sx+3ty-6y=-6s\text{ (we have multiplied the equation by $-3$)}\\3sx-3ty-y=-3s\end{array}\right.,$$
which yields $y=\frac97s$ and $sx-\frac97st+\frac{18}7s=2s\equiv 7x-9t+18=14$.
So $E=\left(\frac{9t-4}{7},\frac97s\right)$ and
$$\overrightarrow{EB}=\left(\frac{12t+4}7,\frac{12s}7\right)$$
$$\overrightarrow{AB}=(3t+1,3s)$$
Then $|EB|/|AB|=4/7$.